Implemnting v-autocomplete
I am trying to implement v-autocomplete, which is basically a searchable select, but I'm not able to pass the customer names data. In the browser console, it shows that the data is invalid. I feel like it's something simple, but I've been stuck on this for a week now.
Here is my code:
`<template>
  <v-container class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
    <v-form @submit.prevent="createLicense" ref="form">
      <!-- Select para Cliente -->
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="selectedClient"
        :items="clients"
        item-text="Nome"  
        item-value="Id"   
        label="Selecione o Cliente"
        :loading="loadingClients"
        no-data-text="Nenhum cliente encontrado"
        outlined
        dense
      ></v-autocomplete>

      <!-- Select para Sistema -->
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="selectedSystem"
        :items="systems"
        item-text="Nome"  
        item-value="Id"   
        label="Selecione o Sistema"
        :loading="loadingSystems"
        no-data-text="Nenhum sistema encontrado"
        outlined
        dense
      ></v-autocomplete>

      <!-- Campo de data de validade -->
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="dataValidade" 
        label="Data de Validade" 
        type="date"
        :rules="[v => !!v || 'Data é obrigatória']" 
        required 
        outlined 
        dense
      ></v-text-field>

      <!-- Campo para quantidade de usuários limitados -->
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="qtdeUsuariosLimitados" 
        label="Quantidade de Usuários Limitados" 
        type="number"
        :rules="[v => v >= 0 || 'Deve ser positivo']" 
        required 
        outlined 
        dense
      ></v-text-field>

      <!-- Campo para quantidade de usuários ilimitados -->
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="qtdeUsuariosIlimitados" 
        label="Quantidade de Usuários Ilimitados" 
        type="number"
        :rules="[v => v >= 0 || 'Deve ser positivo']" 
        required 
        outlined 
        dense
      ></v-text-field>

      <!-- Botão de submissão -->
      <v-btn type="submit" color="primary" class="mt-4" large>Cadastrar Licença</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import LicenseService from '@/services/Licenses/licenses';
import ClientService from '@/services/Clients/clients';
import SystemService from '@/services/Systems/systems';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clients: [],
      systems: [],
      selectedClient: null,
      selectedSystem: null,
      loadingClients: false,
      loadingSystems: false,
      dataValidade: '',
      qtdeUsuariosLimitados: '',
      qtdeUsuariosIlimitados: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getClients() {
      this.loadingClients = true;
      try {
        const response = await ClientService.getAllClients();
        this.clients = response.value.map(({ $id, ...rest }) => rest); // Remove o campo desnecessário
      } catch (error) {
        this.$toast.error('Erro ao buscar clientes');
      } finally {
        this.loadingClients = false;
      }
    },
    async getSystems() {
      this.loadingSystems = true;
      try {
        const response = await SystemService.getAllSystems();
        this.systems = response.value;
      } catch (error) {
        this.$toast.error('Erro ao buscar sistemas');
      } finally {
        this.loadingSystems = false;
      }
    },
    async createLicense() {
      if (!this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        return;
      }

      if (!this.selectedClient || !this.selectedSystem) {
        this.$toast.error('Selecione um cliente e um sistema.');
        return;
      }

      try {
        const selectedClient = this.clients.find(client => client.Id === this.selectedClient);
        const selectedSystem = this.systems.find(system => system.Id === this.selectedSystem);

        const licenseData = {
          Id: 0,
          Cliente: {
            Id: selectedClient.Id,
            Chave: selectedClient.Chave,
            Nome: selectedClient.Nome,
            Email: selectedClient.Email,
            Telefone: selectedClient.Telefone
          },
          Sistema: {
            Id: selectedSystem.Id,
            Nome: selectedSystem.Nome
          },
          Ativa: true,
          DataValidade: this.dataValidade,
          QtdeUsuariosLimitados: this.qtdeUsuariosLimitados,
          QtdeUsuariosIlimitados: this.qtdeUsuariosIlimitados
        };

        await LicenseService.createLicense(licenseData);
        this.$router.push({ name: 'LicenseList' });
        this.$toast.success('Licença criada com sucesso!');
      } catch (error) {
        this.$toast.error('Erro ao criar licença!');
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getClients();
    this.getSystems();
  }
};
</script>


<style scoped></style>`

And this is what the request returns: Request for sistemas:
`{
    "value": [
        {
            "$id": 1,
            "Id": 8,
            "Nome": "Sistema1"
        },
        {
            "$id": 2,
            "Id": 9,
            "Nome": "Sistema2"
        },
        {
            "$id": 3,
            "Id": 10,
            "Nome": "sistema3"
        }
    ]
}`

Request for clientes:
`{
    "value": [
        {
            "$id": 1,
            "Id": 2,
            "Chave": "042176ec-7a2c-499e-881a-496a2c14fa64",
            "Nome": "cliente",
            "Email": "cliente1@gmail.com",
            "Telefone": "99999999"
        },
        {
            "$id": 2,
            "Id": 3,
            "Chave": "ce8fc289-1e68-48e3-9468-4ec1d02ab205",
            "Nome": "cliente2",
            "Email": "cliente2@gmail.com",
            "Telefone": "99999999"
        },
        {
            "$id": 3,
            "Id": 4,
            "Chave": "5d48b749-f724-4479-ad69-e1d408fa677c",
            "Nome": "Cliente3",
            "Email": "cliente3@gmail.com",
            "Telefone": "999999999"
        },
        {
            "$id": 4,
            "Id": 5,
            "Chave": "0d595f88-a350-48dd-a014-d5826459b4f0",
            "Nome": "Cliente4",
            "Email": "Cliente4@gmail.com",
            "Telefone": "999999999"
        }
    ]
}`


If this is Vuetify 3, it should be item-title, not item-text.

Thank you so much, that was it! I can't believe I overlooked that.

Those two are easily mixed up, particularly since item-text was used in v2 and there are still a lot of examples out there using old syntax. Glad it's working!
